# Not able to update Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: updates, dbus

I have **Ubuntu 18.04** and **python 3.7**.

```
uname -a
Linux username-laptop 4.15.0-109-generic #110-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 23 02:39:32 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

When I run `sudo apt-get update` I get this error :

```
E: The repository 'http://dl.bintray.com/aluxian/deb stable Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://dl.bintray.com/aluxian/deb dev Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/891083/1013762) solution but I am also unable to open **Software and updates**.

Comment: I can't even open those in a browser; where did they come from? are they used correctly? and support your release (your lines appear to include typos!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could finally solve the problem myself.
Before that, I did `sudo update-alternatives --config python3` and switched to `python 3.6`
[image: python version change]
After that, I followed the answer of the same post (which I couldn't earlier because Software and updates wouldn't open) and unticked `https://dl.bintray.com/aluxian/deb`. Then the `sudo apt-get update` problem was solved !!!

Answer (score -1):

Probably find the repository is not on `apt-get` anymore. Use `sudo apt update`, it will then tell what packages need to be upgraded. Just upgrade them all by typing in `sudo apt upgrade` in your terminal. Update `snap` as well. Ubuntu relies on `snap` more so than `apt-get` and `apt`. Bit of a grey area in open-source software.

Comment: Sorry, this made no difference. The problem persists. 